# Change page size when Printing as PDF

Tags: pdf, windows-11, print-to-pdf

I have a list of .xhtml document that are size 539*709. This is a kind of weird B5 (190x250mm).

When I do CTRL+P and use the "Save As PDF" feature, I do not have the page format that I want.

How can I fix that ?

System is Windows 11, and I tried using Chrome, Firefox, Edge.
I also managed to create a custom page size in my "print server properties" > "create a new form", but it doesn't appear in the page size selection.

Comment: What operating system and which PDF utility?

Comment: Information added

Comment: You need to publish the file you're trying to print for testing. Which page-size are you trying to print (539*709)?

Comment: @KJ, that seems like a helpful **answer**, more than a comment. Please write what you've done in detail, explaining the steps, so that others can benefit from your experience.